# New MS Teams incoming webhooks is not working in Pipeline Service hook

Tags: azure-pipelines, webhooks, microsoft-teams, azure-service-hooks

we configured Service Hooks notification with old version of Webhooks (starting with https://outlook.office.com/...) before to send notification to Microsoft Teams, which were working fine. However, the new format of Webhooks (starting with https://[hostname].webhook.office.com/...) in Teams is not working in Service Hooks anymore. I always get Bad Request error (400). Anyone has similar issue and get a solution here?
I compared the request from both URLs and didn't find any difference rather than the IDs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmbS6.png)

Comment: Could you please provide any repro steps or more details to check the issue?

Comment: I think I found the root cause from the detailed response with Postman. "Summary or Text is required" is the exact error message. When I added Summary or Text into the request, everything works fine. So it seems Azure Pipeline service hook event doesn't provide these values.
Two questions are:
1. How can this be resolved?
2. Why the old webhook URL doesn't require these two values?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT, does that mean there is no way to use Webhooks to push notification from Pipeline to Microsoft Teams? So we have to use Azure Pipeline app instead?

Comment: We have raised an ICM for the same, the team is looking into it. We will inform you once we have any update.

Comment: Could you please confirm whether the "Summary and Text" field is present when notification is sent to old webhook URL.
These field seems to be a required field, and could you please compare payload in both scenario?